# Questions regarding ternary operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question regarding ternary operations over a set S. Is it true that for any ternary operation h in S, there are binary operations f and g such that h(x,y,z)=f(g(x,y),z)? And the second question is, assuming the answer to the first question is yes, is there an operation f such that h(x,y,z)=f(f(x,y),z)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope! The Boolean [majority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function) operator doesn't have such a decomposition. I'll copy-paste the proof from http://home.comcast.net/%7Etamivox/dave/math/tern_quasi/majority.html:

> Although not a [ternary quasigroup](http://home.comcast.net/%7Etamivox/dave/math/tern_quasi/index.html), the simplest and most familiar nondecomposable ternary function is the majority operation $M$ over values $a$ and $b$, defined by:
>
> 1. $M (a, a, a) = a$
> 2. $M (a, a, b) = a$
> 3. $M (a, b, a) = a$
> 4. $M (a, b, b) = b$
> 5. $M (b, a, a) = a$
> 6. $M (b, a, b) = b$
> 7. $M (b, b, a) = b$
> 8. $M (b, b, b) = b$
>
> Suppose that there were a decomposition $M (p, q, r) = F (p, G (q, r))$. Then we would have:
>
> 1. $F (a, G (a, a)) = a$
> 2. $F (a, G (a, b)) = a$
> 3. $F (a, G (b, a)) = a$
> 4. $F (a, G (b, b)) = b$
> 5. $F (b, G (a, a)) = a$
> 6. $F (b, G (a, b)) = b$
> 7. $F (b, G (b, a)) = b$
> 8. $F (b, G (b, b)) = b$
>
> Observe:
>
> - From 5 and 6, $G (a, a) \neq G (a, b)$.
> - From 2 and 4, $G (a, b) \neq G (b, b)$.
> - From 1 and 4, $G (b, b) \neq G (a, a)$.
>
> Thus $G (a, a)$, $G (a, b)$ and $G (b, b)$ must be three distinct values. However there are only two values to choose from, namely $a$ and $b$, so decomposition fails.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer is no for finite S, it becomes yes for an infinite (well-orderable) S, as we can then take for g a bijection from S×S to S. For the second question, the answer is no : 
Take h(x,y,z)=y. 
f(f(x,y),z)=y=f(f(x,y),z')
f(f(f(x,y),z),t)=z=f(f(f(x,y),z'),t)=z'
while z and z' could differ. Contradiction.